Does automorphism of classifying stack come from automorphism of group?
Let $k$ be a field and $G$ be a group. For simplicity, let us assume $\operatorname{char}k=0$ and $G$ is a finite abelian group. We do not assume $k$ is algebraically closed. If there is an automorphism $\phi: G\to G$, it will induce an automorphism $\phi: \mathbf{B}G\to \mathbf{B}G $, where $\mathbf{B}G$ is the classifying stack of the group $G$ over $\operatorname{Spec}k$. My  question is
Whether all automorphisms between $\mathbf{B}G$ are induced by automorphisms of $G$.

By the comments below, if $k$ is algebraically closed, then it is true.
If $k$ is not algebraically closed, it seems we can construct automorphism of $\mathbf{B}G$ which does not come from automorphism of $G$.

Stacks live in a $2$-category, so automorphisms of a stack form a $2$-group. For $BG$ the automorphism $2$-group should (maybe this needs some hypotheses on the field $k$) be a certain $2$-group built out of the conjugation action of $G$ on $\text{Aut}(G)$, satisfying $\pi_0 \cong \text{Out}(G)$ and $\pi_1 \cong Z(G)$.

@Mike Sure: $BG$ is an Artin stack with affine diagonal, so it's the stack associated to a commutative Hopf algebroid, in this case the Hopf $k$-algebra $k[G]^$, the linear dual of the group ring $k[G]$. You can describe automorphisms of the stack (up to homotopy/$2$-morphisms, I guess) as automorphisms of the Hopf algebra. IMO it's easiest to see it like this: dualize $k[G]^$ to get back to $k[G]$, and observe that an automorphism of $k[G]$ has to send grouplike elements to grouplike elements, so it's got to be a permutation of the elements of $G$, in particular an automorphism of $G$.

@QiaochuYuan The question assumes that $G$ is abelian, so the conjugation action of $G$ on itself is trivial, so in this situation I think we can reasonably treat the $2$-group as an ordinary old group.

@QiaochuYuan: Thanks for the comment. So I wonder, the $\pi_{0}(\mathbf{B}G)=\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ just means all automorphisms of $\mathbf{B}G$ come from $\operatorname{Aut}G$, am I right?

@user509184: Thanks for your comment. If I understand correctly, you mean the following things. First, since $\mathrm{Aut}G$ induces $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf{B}G)$, we have a map (between stacks) $p: \mathrm{Aut}(G)\to \mathrm{Aut}\mathbf{B}G\cong [\mathrm{Aut}G/G] $. $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf{B}G)$ induces a morphism $\mathrm{Aut}G$ just means we have a map $\pi: [\mathrm{Aut}G/G]\to \mathrm{Aut}G $. Moreover, $\pi\circ p=\mathrm{id}$. Am I right?

@Mike Sure. But I'm also saying that this is more transparent if you translate the talk of stacks into talk of Hopf algebras.

@user509184: Thanks a lot for your help. I will try to understand this via Hopf algebras.

Do you want $k$ algebraically closed as well? Otherwise it's not true: $\mathbf{B}G$ has a group structure and translation by non-trivial $k$-points of $\mathbf{B}G$ will give automorphisms of arithmetic nature.

@sdr I do not assume $k$ is algebraically closed. I do not understand your example, can you say more specific?

@user509184 May I can a question again. Did you argument assume $k$ is algebraically closed? It seems you argument works for any field, but I want to make sure.

@Mike In my argument I consider automorphisms of the Hopf $k$-algebra $k[G]^$. You can describe $BG$ in terms of $Spec k[G]^$ once you have chosen a cover of $BG$ by Spec $k$. So my argument describes automorphisms of $BG$ in the category of Artin stacks equipped with a choice of cover by Spec $k$. I suppose that if you have some exotic covers of $BG$ by Spec $k$ then you could get some surprising automorphisms of $BG$ not fixing the cover. I find it plausible that this happens for $$ not algebraically closed.

The homomorphism $m:G \times G \to G$ gives $\mathbf{B}G \times \mathbf{B}G \to \mathbf{B}G$ ($G$ abelian). Take $\mathcal{P}_G \in \mathbf{B}G(k)$ non-trivial (e.g., a Galois extension $k'/k$ with group $G$). Then $\mathbf{B}G \overset{\operatorname{id} \times \mathcal{P}_G}{\to} \mathbf{B}G \times \mathbf{B}G \to \mathbf{B}G$ is an iso. (the inverse is the same, but use $\mathcal{P}_G^{-1}$, the image of $\mathcal{P}_G$ under the map $\mathbf{B}G \to \mathbf{B}G$ induced by the inversion homomorphism). This sends the trivial torsor to $\mathcal{P}_G$ so does not come from an automorphism.
